# Bootstrap Images display different width height ratio?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, image-resizing

I have an image, the image is saved as width 400px and height 400px so its a square image.

On my html page i want it to be squished 400px width and height 200px but still responsive.

How should i be doing this with bootstrap?

I dont want to create all new images. in this case resave as 400px X 200px

Normally i would set the width and height on the img

```
<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("images/Organisations_Summary.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height to 50% and if you want the width to be 400px at the most (widest screen size), you'll want to add a max-width:

CSS

```
img{
    height:50%;
    max-width:450px;
}
```

Comment: <img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" style="height: 40%; max-width:350px;" src="/images/misc/logos/Organisations_Summary.png">